# Using same facebook apikey for heroku production and local development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I would like to test my rails app on my local machine and also have it functional on heroku. However, if I specify my IP address for the "Website" field on the facebook app settings, then my heroku breaks and vice versa. Is there any way to have them both work using the same API Key?

If not, how do I tell Omniauth to use one api key for the development environment and another for the production environment? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate FB app for dev (local) and for production (Heroku).

Read the key out of the environment like:

ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"]
ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"]

Then set the key/creds in your config on Heroku using `heroku config:add`.

Locally use foreman to run your app and set the dev key/creds in a .env file. http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html

Keep in mind that FB requires you to use SSL so you'll need to setup something locally that can handle SSL requests.

Comment: Thanks for the env tip, I ended up just doing this inside omniauth.rb for convenience:

if Rails.env == "development"
  provider :facebook, '123', 'asdf'
elsif Rails.env == "production"
  provider :facebook, '321', 'fdsa'
end

Answer (score 1):

You will either have to create another development Facebook application for development, which is what I do, or you will have to create an entry in your /etc/hosts file that points the hostname of your Heroku app to you local machine.